# CentOS and icewm

Tags: linux, centos

I'm using CentOS 6.3 32bit with 512MB memory and 8GB in a test environment. What would be the command to install icewm desktop in CentOS 6 minimal?

Answer (score 1):

Do you try this command:

```
yum install icewm
```

Look at official `icewm` [page](https://ice-wm.org/):

> RHEL/CentOS packages can be found in the Fedora EPEL repository

Also you can build and install `icewm` from the [source code](https://github.com/bbidulock/icewm)